# Button click event can not be triggered when it triggered blur event for other element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-ng-if

Updated:

In Angular 10, want to display/hide a button base on a boolean value. Code like below:

```
<button mat-icon-button *ngIf="isOnFocus">
  <mat-icon (click)="copyContent()">content_copy</mat-icon>
</button>
<div (focusout)="blur($event)" >{{content}}</div>
```

Before clicking the button, the focus was on `div` element.
The click event on `mat-icon` can not be triggered when the button displayed.

Comment: It is working here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-icon-example-wl3931

Comment: Maniraj, you are right. I found that in my App, the button click triggered another element's `blur` event, so the button click itself was interrupted. Thank you.  I was looking into the wrong direction.

Comment: Event execute order: `mousedown -> blur -> mouseup ->click`. Changed `click` to `mousedown`, all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event execution order: `mousedown -> blur -> mouseup ->click`.
Changed `click` to `mousedown`, and moved the click event to `<button>` tag as BadPiggie suggested, all works fine.

```
<button mat-icon-button *ngIf="isOnFocus" (mousedown)="copyContent()">
  <mat-icon >content_copy</mat-icon>
</button>
<div (focusout)="blur($event)" >{{content}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the `trigger` to the `button` instead of `content`.

```
<button mat-icon-button [hidden]="!isOnFocus" (click)="copyContent()">
  <mat-icon>content_copy</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Tried and the problem still exists.